# Formatting Firebase-response in to an Array

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Real-time Database.

The data structure looks like this:

[image: Picture of (dummy) Database (should look like name --> timeStamp --> ListOfPeople)]

And with my httpRequest (get(URL/name.json))
Request looks like this:

```
return this.http
      .get(
        'URLtoDatabase' +  this.loadedUser + '.json'
      ).pipe(tap(allC =>{
        this.allC = allC;
        console.log(this.allC)
    }));
```

And in an other component I'm Subscribing like this:

```
this.subscription = this.dataStorageService.getAllT().subscribe(
      (allV) => {
        this.allV = allV;
      }
    );
```

I get as response something like this:

```
{timeStamp: Array(11), timeStamp: Array(11), timeStamp: Array(11), timeStamp: Array(11), timeStamp: Array(11), …}
```

but I can't properly get/retrieve any value or array.

Unfortunatly I only get `{undefined}` as a response... and for `response.name.timeStamp1` I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

Could please someone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-)  Can you please share the code you use to make this call?  It looks like you simply need to access one of the properties of the response, something like `response.timeStamp1`

Comment: Thank you! I just edited my post. Thank you for trying to help me:)! BTW I tried it with response.timeStamp1 but since timeStamp1 is a string, I'm not quite sure how I should realize that...

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like maybe you can access by `response.name.timeStamp1`

Comment: @BizzyBob Unfortunatly I only get `{undefined}` as a response... and for `response.name.timeStamp1` I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`